# Map interaction with Dart

Tags: dart

I have a map with values for each letter, when I pass a word it returns the sum of values for each letter, example:

```
test = 1 + 2 + 3 + 1 = 7

t = '1'
e = '2'
s = '3'
```

I thought that this would be working, the idea is to transfer each value to a List and then reduce the list, but perhaps it returns an error.

```
 var splittedString = string.split('');

 for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    sum += values.letterValues[splittedString[i]];
 }
```

In the end I solved it by using different approach, but I would like to know what am I doing wrong.

fyi, different (and better) approach that is working correctly:

```
return input
      .split('')
      .map((s) => values.letterValues[s])
      .fold(0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue + element);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and it works (I've only added `int.parse`)

```
void main() {
  
  final string = 'test';
  final letterValues = {
    't': '1',
    'e': '2',
    's': '3',
  };
  
   var splittedString = string.split('');

  var sum = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    sum += int.parse(letterValues[splittedString[i]]);
 }
  
  print(sum); // result: 7
}
```

Please specify what is going on or deliver your own example.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting crazy about it :)

Comment: @Daniel, your IDE should say something like "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num'" during static analysis process. Dartanalyzer does this magic after configuring IDE to support Dart - configuration for Android Studio: https://dart.dev/tools/jetbrains-plugin